# Issues with JavaFX Translate

Tags: javafx

I have this sample:

```
package bit.fxtest2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TransformTest2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("TransformTest2");
        var bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setCenter(new DragPane());
        var scene = new Scene(bp, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private static class DragPane extends Pane {

        ObjectProperty<Transform> xform = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Translate(0, 0));

        public DragPane() {
            ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseDown = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

            setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                var mousePress = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
                mouseDown.set(mousePress);
            });

            setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                var dragPoint = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
                var delta = dragPoint.subtract(mouseDown.get());
                var t = new Translate(delta.getX(), delta.getY());
                xform.set(xform.get().createConcatenation(t));
                mouseDown.set(dragPoint);
                System.out.println("mp = " + mouseDown);
                updateTransform();
            });

            populate();
            updateTransform();
        }

        private void populate() {
            ObservableList<Node> children = getChildren();
            children.clear();

            children.add(new Line(0, 0, 200, 0));
            children.add(new Line(200, 0, 200, 200));
            children.add(new Line(200, 200, 0, 200));
            children.add(new Line(0, 200, 0, 0));
        }

        private void updateTransform() {
            ObservableList<Transform> transforms = getTransforms();
            transforms.clear();
            transforms.add(xform.get());
        }
    }
}
```

If you run the code, two things happen.

First, as you start dragging, the box drags, but it starts getting very jerky, and bounces back and forth. If you print out the mouse motions they move back and forth.

Second, after you've dragged the box, say, down and to the right, you'll notice that you can no longer drag it in the upper left area of the window.

This is because the Translate is affecting the Pane itself, not necessarily the contents of the Pane. Since the OnMouse handlers are on the Pane itself, and the Pane is no longer in the upper left area, no handlers are called.

So, two questions.

First, why the jerky behavior?

Second, how can I apply Transforms (not just translate) to the children of a pane, and not the pane itself?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the first question (the jerkiness) is that it's because your calculations for the transform are incorrect.

When the dragging is processed, the pane is translated by the amount that was dragged. This leaves the coordinates of the mouse relative to the pane as being the same as they were when the mouse was first pressed.

For example, suppose you click on the pane at `(100,100)`, so `mouseDown` contains the value `(100,100)`. You then drag it, so suppose when the drag event is processed the mouse has moved to `(102,101)` in the pane's coordinate system. Then `delta` will be `(2,1)`, so the pane will be translated by (an additional) `(2,1)`, after which the mouse will again be over the point `(100,100)` in the pane's coordinate system.

Therefore, the correct thing to do here is not to change the value of `mouseDown`.

Simply removing the line

```
mouseDown.set(dragPoint);
```

fixes that issue.

For the second issue: As long as the user starts the drag inside the actual pane, then it all works fine; this seems to be the natural thing to do.

But if you really want to be able to drag from anywhere in the window, you can place the nodes to be dragged in a `Group` and apply the translation to the group. Note that this time, because the `Pane` is not moving, you do need to update the `mouseDown` value:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TransformTest2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("TransformTest2");
        var bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setCenter(new DragPane());
        var scene = new Scene(bp, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private static class DragPane extends Pane {

        ObjectProperty<Transform> xform = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Translate(0, 0));
        
        Group group ;

        public DragPane() {
            ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseDown = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
            group = new Group();
            getChildren().add(group);

            setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                var mousePress = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
                mouseDown.set(mousePress);
            });

            setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                var dragPoint = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
                var delta = dragPoint.subtract(mouseDown.get());
                var t = new Translate(delta.getX(), delta.getY());
                xform.set(xform.get().createConcatenation(t));
                mouseDown.set(dragPoint);
                System.out.println("mp = " + mouseDown);
                updateTransform();
            });

            populate();
            updateTransform();
        }

        private void populate() {
            ObservableList<Node> children = group.getChildren();
            children.clear();

            children.add(new Line(0, 0, 200, 0));
            children.add(new Line(200, 0, 200, 200));
            children.add(new Line(200, 200, 0, 200));
            children.add(new Line(0, 200, 0, 0));
        }

        private void updateTransform() {
            ObservableList<Transform> transforms = group.getTransforms();
            transforms.clear();
            transforms.add(xform.get());
        }
    }

}
```

If you don't want the additional node, you can achieve the same effect by handling the mouse events on the scene, and update the transforms for the pane.